# Calling in android Activity

Tags: android, phone-call

I am making a call in android but i have to make call on 9024651889 but when i make java code in it and when i press call button it makes call on 6236739024651889 means it add something of four to 5 digit no on as suffix to my no. and makes a wrong call can any one tell what can be my problem and how can i fix it

```
String callno = "tel:" + _phoneNO;
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(callno));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

this is code of my calling activity

Comment: Are you sure that _phoneNO variable is "9024651889"? Check it in the debugger or just write out this variable to the log using Log.i("_phoneNo", _phoneNo)

Answer (score 0):

```
String callno = "9024651889";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString(callno)));
context.startActivity(intent);
```